# in electron.js npm start command not working.its saying electron is not recognise as internal or external command

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

```
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried almost everything but finally i able to solved it .

"electron-webpack-quick-start" setup everything for us we don't need to worry about installation of pacakges just run the command and have fun
it worked for me.

1. mkdir new-electron-webpack-project
2. cd new-electron-webpack-project

   3.curl -fsSL https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start/archive/master.tar.gz | tar -xz --strip-components 1
3. git clone https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start.git

5.cd electron-webpack-quick-start

6. rm -rf .git
7. yarn

8.yarn dev

for more info read link below
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start

Answer (score 0):

It seems that electron is not installed yet. In order to run the electron command you need to have node and npm installed and configured correctly then run.

```
npm i -g electron
```

Comment: i am using ubuntu 16.06 i used your recommended command it's showing sh: 1: node: Permission denied  i  also used sudo npm i -g electron

Comment: doesnt work for me. would u mind checking out [my question over here please?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59316390/7543162) <3